# How do I test web application developed in AngularJS with selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to test a web application developed in angularjs, html5 and css3 with selenium webdriver. Currently I am trying to test a login page and when I view the source code of the page, I do not see any html5 code like tags or elements. How do I access these elements if they are hidden?

Comment: Many websites use client-side JavaScript to build part or all of the final rendered page. Whatever browser you're using probably has an "inspector" or developer tool that can help you to examine the page's DOM after it's been loaded and displayed.

Comment: @rutter Thanks for your response. I do not see any DOM for the page. I only see bunch of links for ".css" and sources for .js scripts but no html5 code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force Selenium to wait for AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806399/force-selenium-to-wait-for-angularjs)