# How to scroll down in Python Selenium step by step

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler

Hi guys I am new to Selenium and Python. I was just scraping the site [pagalguy website](https://www.pagalguy.com/discussions/srm-university-25081338). I know how to scroll down to the bottom of the page but what I need is to scroll down step by step so that the Selenium will click all the readmore buttons,but I don't know how to scroll down step by step like that so I hard coded it like following one

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,300);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(300,600);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(600,900);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(900,1200);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1200,1500);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1500,1800);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1800,2100);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()

browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(2100,2500);")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()
it goes on .......
```

I tried automating it using a while loop but it resulted in error, the above one works but I want it short and looped so that I can use it for all the other pages with different page length.

```
initial_value = 0
next_value = 300
while next_value<300000: 
  browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(initial_value,next_value);")
  browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()
  initial_value=next_value
  next_value+=300
```

> JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: initial_value is not
>   defined

But I have defined the value, I think I explained what I am actually trying to do, I want to automatically scroll down and click all the readmore buttons and then I will get the full text content

Comment: You can look into this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver)

Comment: maybe just try to inject some Js like in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194334/8179099)

Comment: @AnkurSingh I tried all of options available in that answer it is scrolling to the page location but it is not clicking and there is no error it executed successfully but thank you for pointing it out though

Comment: @MosheSlavin as i said i am new i dont no angularjs and i refereed to the link that you gave but it didn't help Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agree with answer of @Rahul Chawla.

But adding one change. You can try this one

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

read_mores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[text()="Read More..."]')

for read_more in read_mores:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_more)
    driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", read_more)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked but i have a doubt why is there a $ in the script driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", read_more) it throwed an error then i removed it and now it works

Comment: It's all about javascript coding conventions. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846585/can-someone-explain-the-dollar-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by finding all read more buttons using `find_elements_by_xpath()` and looping over them while scrolling them into view one by one.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

read_mores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[text()="Read More..."]')

for read_more in read_mores:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_more)
    read_more.click()
    # your code here
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is scrolling down to all the readmore clickables but it is not clicking i dont no the reason and there is no error i even added time.sleep(2) between the scrollintoview and click() still it is not cliscking can you give any other suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Use loop with javascript window.scrollBy(0, Y) method with coordinates selecting movement step and iterations number.

```
   for i in range(20): # adjust integer value for need
       # you can change right side number for scroll convenience or destination 
       driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 250)")
       # you can change time integer to float or remove
       time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
while next_value<300000:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({},{});".format(initial_value, next_value))
    browser.find_element_by_link_text("Read More...").click()
    initial_value=next_value
    next_value+=300
```

Basically I just changed this line:
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(initial_value,next_value);")

for this one:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo({},{});".format(initial_value, next_value))
```