# Why using Selenium to scroll down and click the button sometimes fails to load all the page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to load the page with Selenium and parse it with Beautiful Soup. I have tried different ways to simulate the click on the load more button, only the code here works. [[How to scroll down in Python Selenium step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006078/how-to-scroll-down-in-python-selenium-step-by-step])

```
read_mores = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-teach-id='+ tid + ']')
for read_more in read_mores:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", read_more)
    driver.execute_script("$(arguments[0]).click();", read_more)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

However, it fails to load the whole page sometimes. I know probably "clickandwait" will work but have no idea where to put in the code. I would also love to know if there is other way to deal with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there an URL you can share?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do:

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('[data-teach-id=\"" + tid + "\"]').click()")
```

Rather than select in selenium and pass the element to the browser context, do it all in the browser context. Less possiblity for things to go horribly wrong that way.

**Just to get fancy...**

Let's abstract the click to a function (I think I'll do this from now on):

```
def click(css):
  global driver
  driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('" + css + "').click()")
```

Now we can do:

```
click('a[data-teach-id="' + tid + '"]')
```

Ah, much less painful.

Comment: @Chloe Is it just loading some of the content thus pushing the page lower and you would have to click it again? If so, then run that in a loop. If the element is visible `while` you can click it then use that for your conditions.

Comment: Sorry, without an url I can't see what's going on there.